# How to align images and text according to screen size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive

I am new to Bootstrap and need help please.

I have text and images divided in four columns as you can see in my code. I have set alignment according to screen size using media queries (as shown in CSS). BUT if I am resizing the window and reach at the screen size of a tablet view you can say (check Screenshot No. 1) it looks quiet messy as the text is too large and image is too close to the text. So, at THIS screen size i.e. Tablet view, I want my columns to be aligned vertically (like Screenshot No. 2) but I want my image to be on the left side and the text and headings should be next to the image. BUT it shouldn't disturb the Mobile view as everything gets in center in mobile view (check Screenshot No.3) which is perfect for me already.

If still my question is not clear enough then please check the template http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/58152.html

They have section of "Work Team" which I like to have.

I look forward to get help!

Thank you!

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<div id="wrapper"> <!--Wrapper-->
    <div class="container"> <!--Container-->
        <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 40px;">
            <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
                <h1>Meet Us</h1><hr class="style1"></hr>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <img src="images/11.jpg" class="img-circle img-responsive" width="180"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <h2 class="style1">Shaikh Obaidullah</h2>
                <h3 class="style1">CEO / Web Developer</h3>
                <hr class="style2"></hr>
                <p class="style1">I will be taking care of product development stages such as Requirements, Development, Functionality, Usability, and Technical Support.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <img src="images/12.jpg" class="img-circle img-responsive" width="180"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <h2 class="style1">Ovais M. Shaikh</h2>
                <h3 class="style1">Graphic Designer</h3>
                <hr class="style2"></hr>
                <p class="style1">I will spice up your product with creative and unique designs so that you get the most attracted product in the end.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!--Container-END-->
</div> <!--Wrapper-END-->
```

```
    .jumbotron {
    background-image: url('../images/13.jpg');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.img-responsive {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#wrapper {
    background-color: #FFF;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    color: #FFF;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}


hr.style1 {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    border-top: 2px solid #8884bc;
}


@media (min-width: 768px) {
h2.style1{
    color: #8884bc;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h3.style1{
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

hr.style2 {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    border-top: 2px solid #8884bc;
}

p.style1{
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #eee;
}

.jumbotron{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
hr.style2 {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    border-top: 2px solid #8884bc;
}

h2.style1{
    color: #8884bc;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h3.style1{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

p.style1{
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #eee;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I clearly understand You. But i think that your code must be like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <<div class="col-md-5">    
    <div class="left">
      <img>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <h1>
      some text
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>  

  <<div class="col-md-5">    
    <div class="left">
      <img>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <h1>
      some text
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>   
</div>
```

and the class right, must be float:right;, and left float:left; ,amd the col-md-5 must be display: inline-block;

Comment: But in this way, it's like 2 columns of 10 but in Bootstrap we should divide by the columns to make sum of 12, isn't it?

Comment: But it's still not giving a responsive result like the way I want. Please check the codeplay: http://www.codeply.com/go/v16N2uJxbi

Comment: replace fragment of css by this: .right{
 float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  width:50%;
}

.left{
 float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width:50%;
}
img{
    max-width:50%;
}
.col-md-6{
 display: inline-block;
}

Comment: I tried but it's still not being responsive like the way I want. Here is the Codeply: http://www.codeply.com/go/v16N2uJxbi

Comment: so i suggest to add to class="col-md-5"  col-xs-12 so there You will have class="col-md-5 col-xs-12", or col-sm-12 - You must try what is better

Comment: Nope, all of it is actually disturbing the smartphone view and tablet view. I would request you to please check the following template as this is EXACTLY what I want. Check out their Work Team section:

http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/58152.html

Comment: I dont, see any differences. If You want u can send me some screens via imgur or something, so i can see whats going on

Comment: Here are the 3 different screen sizes that I would like to have in my website:

1) http://imgur.com/a/L4Qa2
2) http://imgur.com/h4URmq4
3) http://imgur.com/GBWsERr

Comment: so You only want, in smartphone view, the text will be under the photos?

Comment: Yes, and in the tablet view the columns should be vertically aligned but the text and image should be next to each other.

Comment: So You have to add this code: @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .col-md-6{
 display: inline-block;
    }
    .right{
 width:100%;
    }
    .left{
     max-width:100%;
    }
    img{ max-width:100%; }
}

Probably You have to try what value of max-wdth is good, i try with 800px, but maybe other value will be better

Comment: No, it's still having the same issue. Please check in Codeply:http://www.codeply.com/go/v16N2uJxbi

Comment: You have to add this before .jumbotron, not on the top of css

Comment: No, it's still not working. Check updated Codeplay: http://www.codeply.com/go/v16N2uJxbi

Comment: change max-width: 600px to max-width: 900px

Comment: Nope, still it's not working. I think you are unable to see the Codeply :(
http://www.codeply.com/go/v16N2uJxbi

Comment: i see your code, but i think this is what You need, there behavoiur of divs are exactly the same as on example. http://imgur.com/a/lX87R

Comment: Yes, this is nearly same. But if you check the Smartphone view, the image is not in center and I want this image to be in center. I hope you can help me with that?

Comment: use that code: @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {  .right{ width:100%; } .left{ max-width:100%;float:none;width: 100%; } img{ max-width:100%; } }